# This is my wallpapers downloading code, it works on only Google Photo

Tags: android, image, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, download

This is my wallpapers downloading code. It works on only Google Photo. Please give me the simplest code to single click download the wallpapers.

How to download wallpaper in one click into gallery automatically?

```
private void downloadWallpaper(final Wallpaper wallpaper) {
                ((Activity) mCtx).findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                Glide.with(mCtx)
                        .asBitmap()
                        .load(wallpaper.url)
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                                  @Override
                                  public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                                      ((Activity) mCtx).findViewById(R.id.progressbar).setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

                                      Uri uri = saveWallpaperAndGetUri(resource, wallpaper.id);

                                      if (uri != null) {
                                          intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
                                          mCtx.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Islamic Writes"));
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                        );
            }




    private Uri saveWallpaperAndGetUri(Bitmap bitmap, String id) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mCtx, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    if (ActivityCompat
                            .shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) mCtx, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction( Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);

                        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", mCtx.getPackageName(), null);
                        intent.setData(uri);

                        mCtx.startActivity(intent);

                    } else {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mCtx, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 100);
                    }
                    return null;
                }

     File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Download");
                folder.mkdirs();

                File file = new File(folder, id + ".jpg");
                try {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();

                    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE );
                    mCtx.sendBroadcast(intent);

                    return FileProvider.getUriForFile( mCtx, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +".provider",file );
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: perhaps, instead of asking for code, you could explain what doesn't work or what problems you're having

Comment: Nothing problem... I want to direct download into gallery..